# Usefulness of eigenvalue centrality

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, network

Question for the network theorists/computer scientists: I heard that the eigenvalue centrality is "useless" and "too sensitive to jump behavior" for directed graphs.

$\bullet$ What does this mean exactly?

$\bullet$ Can one say for which graphs eigenvalue centrality work or doesn't work, and in what sense precisely?

$\bullet$ What are then the alternatives that avoid these problems?

Question is necessarily vague due to my ignorance of network theory but I am getting the impression that this is part of network theory folklore. Any reference is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Centrality measures have very different uses. You cannot really generally say that one is "better" than another. This is always context dependent.

Eigenvector centrality, in general, is certainly not a useless concept, it is the most simple "reputation based" centrality metric, in the sense that you earn reputation/centrality, if you are connected to other high centrality nodes. As such it is the basis for PageRank, being an eigenvector centrality of a modified adjacency matrix (basically allowing a random walker to jump).

For general information and improvement of "literacy" on network centrality measures (i.e. for what situations is what metric suitable) see e.g.

[1] http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.131.8175&rep=rep1&type=pdf

[2] Mark Newman, Networks: an introduction

[3] http://www.analytictech.com/borgatti/papers/centflow.pdf

On EVC and PageRank specifically (sorry, seems like I cannot post more than two links):

[4] Wikipedia: PageRank

[5] Page, L. and Brin, S., The PageRank citation ranking: bringing order to the web, 1999

[6] ... google scholar has more ...

Where did you read it is useless, and in which context?

----- Edit 1 ----
I have no idea what exactly was meant by "too sensitive to jump behavior", without details about the context. Was it some CS seminar, talking about importance ranking of webpages? I mean, the only thing I can imagine right now that could have been meant (in a strange way), is that PageRank is often used instead of EVC, as it allows a random walker to "jump", i.e. to visit a not-neighboring node. In a web page ranking scenario this is meant to account for random encounter of new webpages, hence avoiding a random walker to get stuck in some dense cluster. If this was meant, the Brin Page paper is a good explanation on why PageRank performs better than EVC, in the webpage ranking scenario. Otherwise see Newman book, for a more pedagogical intro.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your answer.

Comment: I heard that statement thrown out in a seminar talk. Could you elaborate/suggest references for the "too sensitive to jump behavior" part?

Comment: @Michael see my edit above